# Is there a Jewish tradition according to which each creative day was 7000 years?

Tags: time, creation

I remember hearing (long ago, so it could be that I remember wrong) that, according to a Jewish tradition, the last day of creation (Gods day or rest) is 7000 years long and that consequently the other 6 days (since they were the same length) would also be 7000 years long.

Is it correct that this type of tradition exists?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88207/questions-about-the-7000-year-shmita-cycles

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a tradition, but [there are those](http://www.icr.org/bible/Psalm/90/4/) who interpret the verse in Psalms "[For a thousand years in your eyes is like a passing day](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6_%D7%93)" (loose translation) to mean that when God speaks about days in the Creation story they are actually referring to 1,000 year eons.